# How to use PowerShell alias cd a spec directory?

Tags: powershell, alias

On Linux

```
alias cdt='cd /usr/a'
```

make a alias that when I type

```
cdt
```

I change the workpath to /use/a

On PowerShell

```
Set-Alias cdt "cd F://a"
```

It seems not work

Comment: [Example 5](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849938.aspx#code-snippet-5) should help.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Aliases can't use parameters, so define a function instead.

```
function cdt { set-location "F:\a" }
```

Comment: oh，if this, I will use .bat in cmd to avoid learning a new thing -- powershell.  thx

Comment: I would encourage you not to give up on PowerShell. It is superior to cmd.exe in nearly every conceivable way. It is object-oriented and you can accomplish a lot with little effort.

Comment: @mingchaoyan You will find a much more rich ecosystem and community with PowerShell IMO.  For instance, check out a module that already does what you want - https://github.com/tkellogg/Jump-Location  And if you have Chocolatey, you can install it like so - choco install Jump-Location

Comment: I don't really understand the point of aliases then. Why not just always define a function with no params and just call it directly?

Comment: An alias is just a command substitute and nothing more. If you want more, you can use a function.

Comment: How to I save it permanently so each time I open the PowerShell the function still exists?

Comment: Ok found it: https://www.gsx.com/blog/bid/81096/enhance-your-powershell-experience-by-automatically-loading-scripts

Comment: Now use https://github.com/vors/ZLocation instead of Jump-Location. <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> is very nice.

Comment: @Smeterlink the URL is now a 404, so for future reference to others, you may add to your existing $profile file, or create new $profile file via: `New-Item -Path $profile -ItemType File -Force`, followed by adding the function in the created $profile file via e.g. `notepad $profile`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc895642(v=msdn.10) for more information.

Answer (score 17):

To make sure this stays as a permanent alias you can do the following in powershell:

```
notepad $profile
```

and paste the following in the file (at the end):

```
function gotoa { set-location "F:\a" }
new-alias cdt gotoa
```

Comment: If you get an error editing $PROFILE, it needs to be created first: `New-Item -path $PROFILE -type file –force`

Comment: Also, be sure your ps shell is allowed to attach this created .ps file. To do it run 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned' and 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser', after this - reload shell. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Edit your PS profile file to add something like following:
(If you need to find the location of your PS profile, type `$profile` in PS terminal and it will give you the path to the profile file.)

```
$work= @{
    project = 'C:\folder1\work\project'
    webapp = 'C:\folder1\work\project\wars\webapp\src\main\webapp'
    components = 'C:\folder1\work\project\components'
    build = 'C:\folder1\work\project\build'
}
```

Restart the Powershell and then you can `cd` as following:

```
cd $work.webapp
```

Instead of restarting the terminal you can just reload the profile as following

```
. $profile
```