# Why does this Powershell function to change directory not work?

Tags: function, powershell, alias

I use a Powershell window with posh-git to work with git and have grown tired of repeatedly typing `cd ..\Database`, `cd ..\Backend` and `cd ..\Frontend` to switch between the repos I'm working with. I want to create aliases so that I can simply run `db`, `be` or `fe` to do this.

After some reasearch and failed experimentation I was getting nowhere and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29716532/1535) which informs that aliases can't take parameters and I should use functions, so I tried that.

I can successfully change to one the desired directories with the command

```
Set-Location C:\Projects\Database
```

so I executed the following in a Powershell window to create a function

```
function db { set-location C:\Projects\Database }
```

and this executed without error. However on running `db` immediately afterwards, I get the following error.

```
db : The term 'Set-Location C:\Projects\Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ db
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-Location C:\Projects\Database:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I want to ultimately add commands to create the functions to my profile script, but have been unable to get past this simple block and am feeling quite frustrated that I can't get what would seem to be a simple thing to work.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Your script is working perfectly for me. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: `Remove-Item alias::db`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. As soon as I saw the comment from @PetSerAl I had a DOH! moment. Of course what had happened was the `db` alias was still there and as I've now learned aliases take precedence over functions. Once I removed all aliases and functions I had tried, then recreated the `db` one, it worked fine. Problem solved.

Comment: @PetSerAl You should make that an answer. I'm sure there's a ton of people who've run into that issue and were left scratching their heads not even thinking of an alias taking precedence.

Comment: I will but think there's a delay before I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message complaining about `Set-Location C:\Projects\Database` command not found, but command being marked as error is `db`. The only reasonable explanation of this error message I can find, is that `db` command is an alias to `Set-Location C:\Projects\Database`. You possibly try to create an alias before trying to make function. Aliases have higher precedence than functions. So that, even you have `db` function now, `db` still resolved as an alias and produce error. You have to remove alias `Remove-Item Alias::db`, then `db` would be resolved to function.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what had happened. I initially tried creating an alias and had left it behind when I moved on to trying a function.